# Ignore dtype exceptions when importing csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a natural-valued variable, e.g. "age" in my csv-Dataset. This dataset is flowed, since some of the values are strings, e.g. "missing".

This code

```
personal_info = pd.read_csv("Age.csv", sep=',')
```

gives me the error

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (6,10) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

Adding dtype

```
personal_info = pd.read_csv("Age.csv", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False,
                               dtype={'age': int})
```

blows up when encountering the string "missing".

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'missing'
```

How do I ignore the rows with the values not in the variable domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `na_values` argument :

```
personal_info = pd.read_csv("Age.csv", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False,
                           dtype={'age': int},na_values=['missing'])
```

Comment: How does it now that na_values refer to the column 'age' and not, for instance, "height"?

Comment: it applies to all columns, do you have other columns where you want to keep "missing" as a valid value ?

Comment: I do not, but this may be the case for the users who will view this question in the future :)